# Why do I not need @Autowired on @Bean methods in a Spring configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Why does this work:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  public A getA() {
    return new A();
  }

  @Bean               // <-- Shouldn't I need @Autowired here?
  public B getB(A a) {
    return new B(a);
  }  
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`@Autowire` lets you inject beans from context to "outside world" where outside world is your application.
Since with `@Configuration` classes you are within "context world ", there is no need to explicitly autowire (lookup bean from context).

Think of analogy like when accessing method from a given instance. While you are within the instance scope there is no need to write `this` to access instance method, but outside world would have to use instance reference.

**Edit**

When you write `@Configuration` class, you are specifying meta data for beans which will be created by IOC.

`@Autowire` annotation on the other hand lets you inject **initialized** beans, not meta-data, in application. So, there is no need for explicit injection because you are not working with Beans when inside `Configuration` class.

Comment: Thanks! Is this written somewhere in the Spring docs? Where the boundary between "outside" and "context" worlds lies? :)

Comment: That is a good question and i am not sure if there is explicit documentation about this. The boundary would be @Configuration (which makes class marked as one containing beans definitions for IOC). Hopefully i am not mistaken, but you shouldn't be able to omit autowire in anything which is not Configuration.

Comment: From the Javadoc of Configuration: "@ Configuration is meta-annotated with @ Component, therefore @ Configuration classes are candidates for component scanning ([...]) and therefore may also take advantage of @ Autowired/@ Inject at the field and method level (but not at the constructor level)." To me, this actually seems to indicate that I *need* to use @ Autowired on @ Bean methods... Unless @ Bean methods are somehow doubly-special and excluded from the above prescription. Ah, the magic of Spring. :)

Comment: Got it :) You need autowire if you inject between different configuration classes: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s02.html  but not internally - scroll previos to chapters to 2.2 . This makes sense because when one @Configuration class is scaned and meta data processed, there are initialized beans in IOC.

Answer (score 11):

Hi Jan your question is marked as answered over 4 years ago but I've found a better source:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/javaconfig-methods-inter-dependency.html

here's another article with the same idea:
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-configuration-and, it also states that such usage is not well documented which I found true. (?)

so basically if `beanA`'s initialization depends on `beanB`, spring will wire them without explicit `@Autowired` annotation as long as you declare these two beans in the application context (i.e. `@Configuartion` class).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A class with @Configuration annotation is where you're defining your beans for the context. But a spring bean should define its own dependencies. Four your case B class should be defining it's own dependencies in class definition. For example if your B class depends on your A class than it should be like below:

```
public class B
{
    @Autowired
    A aInstance;

    public A getA()
    {
        return aInstance;
    }

    public void setA(A a)
    {
        this.aInstance =  a;
    }
}
```

In above case while spring is building its context it looks for the bean which's type is A which is also defined as a Bean at your configuration class and Autowires it to B at runtime so that B can use it when required.

Comment: Hmm .. I'm afraid this doesn't seem to answer my question. I'm asking why the code I pasted above works without @ Autowired, not how B should be written. I'm just curious how @ Autowired works, exactly. The docs don't seem to explain it in its entirety.