# Autowiring conflict in spring core with the xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Taking as reference the post [Spring @Autowired and @Qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830548/spring-autowired-and-qualifier)

We have this example to fix the autowiring conflict :

```
public interface Vehicle {
     public void start();
     public void stop();
}
```

There are two beans, `Car` and `Bike` implements `Vehicle` interface.

```
@Component(value="car")
public class Car implements Vehicle {

     @Override
     public void start() {
           System.out.println("Car started");
     }

     @Override
     public void stop() {
           System.out.println("Car stopped");
     }
 }

@Component(value="bike")
public class Bike implements Vehicle {

     @Override
     public void start() {
          System.out.println("Bike started");
     }

     @Override
     public void stop() {
          System.out.println("Bike stopped");
     }
}

@Component
public class VehicleService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bike")
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public void service() {
         vehicle.start();
         vehicle.stop();
    }
}
```

That's a very good example to fix this problem.

But when I have the same problem but without those balises in the application context:

```
<context:component-scan></context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

**All the issues are solved by using the `@Qualifier` annotation, but in my case we don't use the balise that permit to use annotation.**

The question is :

How can I fix this issue just using the configuration in application context, that's it, **without using annotations**?

I searched a lot and [I found people talking about `autowire` attribute in the bean declaration `<bean id="dao" class="package.IDao" autowire="byName"></bean>`](https://dzone.com/articles/explain-major-benefits-amp-limits-of-auto-wiring-i) and I need more explanation about it.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/explain-major-benefits-amp-limits-of-auto-wiring-i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I fix this issue just using the configuration in application
>   context?

You could use the `qualifier` tag like below (see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

```
<context:annotation-config/>
  <beans>
    <bean class="your_pkg_route.Vehicle">
      <qualifier value="bike"/>
    </bean>
  </beans>
</context:annotation-config>
```

> I found people talking about autowire attribute in the bean
>   declaration and I need more explanation about it

**Using Annotation**

[`@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) used on a bean declaration method injects the defined dependencies by (another) declared beans. Now, if your dependencies are in the same context of your application, you don't need to use the `@Autowired` annotation at all because Spring is able to figure them out by itself. So, if your dependencies are outside your applicatoin context then you can use it.

For example, take as reference the below code:

```
@Autowired
@Bean
public MyBean getMybean(Dependency1 depdency1, Dependency2 depdency2) {
    return new MyBean(depdency1.getSomeStuff(), depdency2.getSomeOtherStuff());
}
```

Here, `@Autowired` will find an instance of `Dependency1` and `Dependency2` and will provide them for the creation of an instance of `MyBean`.

**Using xml configuration**

From [Pro Spring 5](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484228074)... Spring supports five modes for autowiring.

- `byName`: When using `byName` autowiring, Spring attempts to wire each property to a bean of the same name. So, if the target bean has a property named `foo` and a `foo` bean is defined in `ApplicationContext`, the `foo` bean is assigned to the `foo` property of the target.
- `byType`: When using `byType` autowiring, Spring attempts to wire each of the
  properties on the target bean by automatically using a bean of the same type in
  `ApplicationContext`.
- `constructor`: This functions just like `byType` wiring, except that it uses constructors rather than setters to perform the injection. Spring attempts to match the greatest numbers of arguments it can in the constructor. So, if your bean has two constructors, one that accepts a `String` and one that accepts `String` and an `Integer`, and you have both a `String` and an `Integer` bean in your `ApplicationContext`, Spring uses the two-argument constructor.
- `default`: Spring will choose between the `constructor` and `byType` modes
  automatically. If your bean has a default (no-arguments) constructor, Spring uses
  `byType`; otherwise, it uses constructor.
- `no`: This is the default

So, in your case you would need to do something like this (BUT, I would NOT recommend it. Why?, you would need to declare `Vehicle` class as a bean and a component which is not correct, see [Spring: @Component versus @Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604298/spring-component-versus-bean). On the other hand I'm not sure if you could use it just declaring it as a bean):

```
// xml config
<context:annotation-config/>
  <beans>

    // use the primary tag here too! in order to say this the primary bean
    // this only works when there are only two implementations of the same interface
    <bean id="bike" primary="true" class="your_pkg_route.Bike"/>
    <bean id="car" class="your_pkg_route.Car"/>         

    <bean autowire="byName" class="your_pkg_route.VehicleService"/>

  <beans>
</context:annotation-config>

// VehicleService
@Component
public class VehicleService {

    private Vehicle bike;   // call attribute 'bike' so it is autowired by its name

    public void service() {
         //...
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a lot of complications trying to do this using xml config, so I would recommend you to use the annotation option if possible.

Related posts:

- [Why do I not need @Autowired on @Bean methods in a Spring configuration class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078600/why-do-i-not-need-autowired-on-bean-methods-in-a-spring-configuration-class)
- [Difference between @Bean and @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172888/difference-between-bean-and-autowired)

PS: I have not tested any of the posted codes.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

You can use [@Primary](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary) instead of `@Qualifier`

```
@Primary
@Component(value="bike")
public class Bike implements Vehicle {
```

> we use @Primary to give higher preference to a bean when there are multiple beans of the same type.
>
> We can use @Primary directly on the beans

You can also set primary attribute in [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548471/spring-xml-equivalent-of-primary):

> property has primary attribute:
>
> ```
> <bean primary="true|false"/>
> ```
>
> If a @Primary-annotated class is declared via XML, @Primary annotation metadata is ignored, and  is respected instead.