# Spring bean injection conflict src/main vs src/test

Tags: java, spring

I have two implementations for a given interface both are annotated with @Component.

One implementation is in src/main -> IImplementationCore.java
Other implementation is in src/test -> IImplementationTest.java

I have a test class ABCTest.java in src/test which is annotated with

> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), @SpringBootTest, @ContextConfiguration,
> @ComponentScan, @EnableAutoConfiguration

I want this ABCTest.java to inject IImplementationCore while running the test. But it is injecting IImplementationTest.java.

package structure:

- src

  - main

    - package

      - IImplementationCore.java
  - test

    - package

      - IImplementationTest.java
    - package2

      - ABCTest.java

Solution I know:

- Annotating @Primary for IImplementationCore.java resolves the issue.

I somehow do not like to force something as primary because it is being annotated as primary due to some bean conflict from src/test but not due to some real conflict in core implementations.
what are my other options? What I am looking for is, is there a way to only consider beans from src/main but not from src/test? Or is there any better way?

Comment: you can use a Qualifier

Comment: are you saying to add qualifier in ABCTest.java while autowiring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autowiring conflict in spring core with the xml configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572845/autowiring-conflict-in-spring-core-with-the-xml-configuration)

Comment: I am saying you could google to find out what a Qualifier is and how it works. A Qualifier is used to decide between implementations.

Comment: @MedElgarnaoui he is using annotations, not xml

Comment: @Stultuske this post mentioned also the Qualifier annotation, take a look, thanks for your precision

Comment: sure for Qualifier. I gave names for those components saying Component(value="core") and Component(value="test"). But when I tried to use Qualifier, it shows compile error saying "cannot find method value". However Named annotation works and I used Named("core") but it still is injecting Component(value="test"). confused.

Comment: i used the wrong import of Qualifier, however after fixing, still not injecting the right bean

Comment: I have also tried to excludeFilters in component scan, so i can exclude the package scan of this unwanted test bean, still is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation on your implementations. It will load a bean only if specified profile/s are currently active.

```
@Component
@Profile({"a", "b"})
public IImplementationCore implements YourInterface {
}
```

Specify the profiles for test implementation the same way.

If this test class is very specific, like being the only one needing implementation core, you can use [@ActiveProfiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html#:%7E:text=ActiveProfiles%20is%20a%20class%2Dlevel,to%20create%20custom%20composed%20annotations.) on it to activate profile different from current for this test class only.

```
//other annotations
@ActiveProfiles("a")
public TestClass {
}
```